Fitting data to a system of ODE using ParametricNDSolveValue
I am trying to create the following code to fit data to a system of ODE.
Clear[s, i, r, t, b, k];
EquacaoS = s'[t] == -b*s[t]*i[t]
EquacaoI = i'[t] == b*s[t]*i[t] - k*i[t]
EquacaoR = r'[t] == k*i[t]
ParametricSolution = ParametricNDSolveValue[{EquacaoS, EquacaoI, EquacaoR, s[0] == s0, 
   i[0] == 0.0001, r[0] == 0.0000}, {s, r, i}, {t, 0, 100}, {b, k, 
   s0}]

And the data which i have avaiable is:
 Data = {{0, 0}, {1, 1.78`}, {2, 6.28`}, {3, 1.39`}, {4, 9.61`}, {5,51}, {6, 455.06`}, {7, 652.89`}, {8, 79.32`}, {9, 39.19`}, {10,5.08`}, {11, 0.38`}, {12, 0}}

I am trying to fit the "i" curve into data. I manipulated the plot, and found some approximate values:
    Manipulate[Show[Plot[ParametricSolution[b, k, s0][[3]][t], {t, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> {0, 1000}], 
ListPlot[Data, PlotRange -> {0, 800}]], {b, 0.0001, 0.1}, {k, 0, 1, 0.1}, {s0, 100, 2000, 10}]

Which results in:

Then i tried to use NonlinearModelFit to find exactly what parameters are, but it didn't work:
fit = NonlinearModelFit[Data, ParametricSolution[b, k, s0][[3]][t], {{b, .004}, {k, 0.3}, {s0, 820}}, t]


Can someone, please, help me with this? I would like to find the exact parameters. Thank you.


We use Indexed[#,3] to get the third part.
We add condition { b > 0, k > 0, s0 > 500} in such fit.

nlmf = NonlinearModelFit[
  Data, {Indexed[ParametricSolution[b, k, s0], 3][t], b > 0, k > 0, 
   s0 > 500}, {b, k, s0}, t, Method -> "NMinimize"]
par = nlmf["BestFitParameters"]
Show[Plot[nlmf[t], {t, 0, 13}, PlotStyle -> Orange], 
 ListPlot[Data, PlotStyle -> Blue], PlotRange -> All]


{b -> 0.000872891, k -> 3.77743, s0 -> 7358.62}.


NonlinearModelFit[Data, 
 Indexed[ParametricSolution[b, k, s0], 3][t], {b, {k, 3}, {s0, 5000}},
  t]

also work.

Hello cvgmt. I can't thank you enough. Thank you very, very much! God bless you. Excellent work.
